# What does &gt; 0 mean in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL statement. Please tell me if my translation of it is accurate. I'm using MS SQL Server 2008. Thanks

```
(bld_sqft &gt; 0 OR bld_area &gt; 0)
```

My translation

```
bld_sqft > 0 OR bld_area > 0
```

Comment: I believe the above translation is correct. &gt; is just representation for the '>' symbol (more: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: Is this an expression in a BI package stored as XML?

Comment: Yes this is in an XML file that is converted to a JSP, which displays the user interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&gt;` is an HTML entity (typically used because HTML uses `<>` for markup), that is not valid SQL and it should not run unless it is being translated to `>` before being sent to SQL Server.

See http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref for information about HTML entities.

Comment: @Siva OK, it doesn't error out for my user id, that's kind of odd, but I've expanded the data type.  I didn't even realize I had a top 5 favorited query on SEDE!

Answer (score 3):

Where are you getting this SQL statement?  You are right that > translates to the greater than symbol, but it was encoded to the entity character reference.  It is almost as if the encoded value was being treated literally when displayed on a web page.

[EDIT]
As you can see, when I typed that symbol, it actually rendered as a > symbol in my post...

A good hint is if you see the ampersand (&) followed by two to four characters then a semi-colon, it was supposed to render differently:

http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html
[/EDIT]

Comment: I think he got that syntax from .xml file